# Is there a name for "tables generations" in relational modeling?

Tags: database, database-design, theory

I mean, when I'm designing DBs, I find tables with no parents, let say "free tables", and others that are their childs, and childs of the childs...
Let me try to be more formal:
- Let say **->** means "references to..."
- Let say **[tableName]** is a table
Consider this:

> [cell]->[organism]->[community]->[region]->[planet]

According with my first approach, [planet] is a "free table", but [cell] has a certain amount of "references to" in secuence, 4 acctually. [planet] has 0, [community] has 2.
I guess it is kind of a grade... Here born my question, Is there a formal name for that number?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no name for that number, as many tables reference multiple tables and so have multiple numbers. From a system I'm currently working on:

```
StructureElement -> Generator ->PlugIn -> PlugInType
```

PlugInType is only a sort of description identifying what sort of work the PlugIn's of that type do.

```
StructureElement -> Calendar -> CalendarType
```

What calendar it's using.

Also, you get hierarchical relationships. A StructureElement can be part of another StructureElement, so you have

```
StructureElement -> StructureElement
```

That could conceptually go on for infinity, but my software limits it to 10 levels. What is the number of StructureElement?

Cheers -

Comment: while I was reading your answer, I though "well, let's say -the max number-"... but with the recursive case, it make no sense. Thanks

Comment: Actually, what I think makes most sense is the number of tables it depends on. In this case StructureElement depends on 3 tables: Generator, Calendar, and StructureElement. The higher the number of direct dependancies the more complex it is.

Comment: Yes, but anyway, there is not name for that, right? :/

Comment: Number of dependencies?